# java- how do I go about writing a for loop that counts up?

Tags: java

Need help with this if possible. I'm getting only one output of "-3". I am trying to figure out how to have it print out "-3 -2 -1 0 " .

```
public class ForLoops {
public static void main (String [] args) {
  int numVal;
  int i;

  numVal = -3;

  for(i=-3; i >= numVal; i--) {
     System.out.print(i + " ");
  }

}
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is homework help and you haven't explained what you've tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

`-3 < -2 < -1 < 0` since they are negative numbers. What you need to do is actually increment.

```
for(i=-3; i <= 0; i++) {
     System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`"-3 -2 -1 0 "` is actually counting up.

So just do a regular loop starting at -3 and incrementing once in each loop.

```
for(i=-3; i <= 0 ; i++) {
    System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```